# Date Time Conversion for Mysql query

Tags: php, date, time

How to convert this Date format :

> 2017-12-20 09:26:03

To:

> 2017-10-05T09:31:00.000Z

I am getting date values from **mysql db** in the format

2017-10-05T09:31:00.000Z

and in my PHP block I am getting $this->date->gmtDate() in the format

2017-12-20 09:26:03

. In my query I have to fetch values from the database column **greate**r than the current datetime. If some one can sort out how to convert the date format I would be able to fetch the values from the date column.

My Query is :

```
$date = $this->date->gmtDate();          
 $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
  ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
  ->addFieldToFilter('_end_date', array('gteq' => $date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL function **DATE_FORMAT**, with params for SELECT.

See to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

Or store date in database as *datetime* type.

Comment: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m-%d %T);`

Answer (score 0):

> database column greater than the current datetime

MySQL understands GMT datetimes:

```
// Using PDO
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE dateColumn > ?");

$stmt->execute(array( $this->date->gmtDate() ));

while ($tuple = $stmt->fetch()) {
    ... do something with the fetched rows
}
```

However, in **this** case:

> I have to fetch values from the database column greater than the current datetime

...you don't even need PHP at all, since "current datetime" is available in MySQL with the `NOW()` function:

```
SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE dateColumn > NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

`Z` is based on timezone `UTC` and is defined in [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which you want.

You need to transfer to UTC before converting to the actual format:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d\TH-i-s.\0\0\0\Z');
```

Then you can compare above format string.

Answer (score 0):

please use this ...

```
$originalDate = "set your date ...";
$newDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($originalDate));
```

Comment: The original date is *already* in Y-m-d H:i:s format. This only has the effect of getting the wrong time in the afternoon - as you used h instead of H, so that 18:00:00 becomes 06:00:00.